# Android Retrofit not showing error and not working also

Tags: php, android, image, upload, retrofit

Below Retrofit declaration is not working i have implemented proper modules in **build.gradel**. For few days the code was working fine, suddenly it stopped working and not giving any error also.

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(MyImageInterface.IMAGEURL)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .build();


public interface MyImageInterface {``
String IMAGEURL = connect.cons+"book_insert.php";
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("book_insert.php")
Call<String> getImageData(
        @Field("name") String name,
        @Field("image") String image
);
}
 I have applied following solution for retrofit connection as suggested
public class ApiClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

static final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

  public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
        try {
            if (retrofit == null) {

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setLenient()
                        .create();

                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(MyImageInterface.IMAGEURL)
                        
                  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .build();
            }
                            }catch(Exception e)
                         {
                               Log.v("retroerror",e.getMessage());
                          }
                    return retrofit;
                           }
              }
```

but giving me
error
"baseUrl must end in /:
[http://13387c25fbd0.ngrok.io/my1/book_insert.php"](http://13387c25fbd0.ngrok.io/my1/book_insert.php%22)

Comment: Post the code where you make the call with  Retrofit

Answer (score 0):

**For Connection try this out**

```
public class ApiClient {
 
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){

        if(retrofit==null){

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                            .setLenient()
                            .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(base_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

You can create your connection with your interface like this, then you to enqueue your call by interface funtions.

```
ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class)
```

Comment: if you want more details ask me.