# Getting the API, Android Studio static

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting a problem where `PlaceholderAPI.getPosts();` is showing
`Non-static method 'getPosts()' cannot be referenced from a static context`
I'm just starting so I'm going through a tutorial (I have some experience in programming android apps but not much)
the code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
                .build();
        Call<List> call = PlaceholderAPI.getPosts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List> call, Response<List> response)
            {
                Log.d("Yo", "Success!");                
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Log.d("Yo", "Error!");
            }
        });
        Log.d("Yo","Hello World!");
    }
```

the code for PlaceholderAPI.java is an interface with code:

```
@GET("posts")
    Call<List> getPosts();
```

Comment: go through my answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248763/12596713

Answer (score 1):

`PlaceHolderAPI.getPosts()` isn’t a static method. Calling a method against the class requires that method to be static.

You need to do one of two things:

Change the interface’s method:

```
static Call<List> getPosts
```

Access an object that implements the `PlaceHolderAPI` interface - let’s call the object `placeHolderObj` and call the method on that object:

```
placeHolderObj.getPosts()
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Connection** create a `ApiClient`  class.

```
public class ApiClient {
 
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static final String base_URL ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
    static final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){

        if(retrofit==null){

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                            .setLenient()
                            .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(base_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

You can create your connection with your interface like this, then you can enqueue your call by interface functions.

```
   PlaceholderAPI placeholder= ApiClient.getApiClient().create(PlaceholderAPI.class);
  Call<List> call = PlaceholderAPI.getPosts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List> call, Response<List> response)
            {
                Log.d("Yo", "Success!");                
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Log.d("Yo", "Error!");
            }
        });
        Log.d("Yo","Hello World!");
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to understand the code because it didn't solve my problem. ".getPosts()" was still referenced from a static context...